# Looking up values in a map with a vector of integer keys in Clojure

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure, key-value

I have a map like this:

```
(def my-map {43423 43.3, 63452 32.02, 823828 67.43, ...})
```

and a vector of keys that are in a different order:

```
(def my-keys [63452 823828 43423 ...])
```

How can I call the my-keys vector on my-map to pull out the values and maintain the order of the vector, as below?

```
;=> [32.02 67.43 43.3 ...]
```

Any datatype returned is fine as long as the order is maintained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map`

```
(map my-map my-keys)
;=> (32.02 67.43 43.3)
```

This works because `{}` maps implement the function interface by looking up the argument in themselves.

```
({:foo 1 :bar 2} :bar)
;=> 2
```